# Show that the composition of the two functions is the identity.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have to check that the composition of the following functions gives the identity (or that one function is the inverse of the other):

$$\pi:S^2\backslash \{N\}\to\mathbb{C}$$

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto \frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}$$

$$\psi : \mathbb{C}\to S^2\backslash \{N\}$$

$$z=x_1+ix_2 \mapsto\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}(2x_1,2x_2,x_1^2+x_2^2-1)$$

Where $S^2$ is the unite sphere and N the north pole (is not important for the problem).

I'm having trouble with the calculus and I don't know where my mistakes is, can you maybe see it?

This is what I've done so far:

$$\pi(\psi(z))=\pi \space (\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}(2x_1,2x_2,x_1^2+x_2^2-1))=\frac{\frac{2x_1 + 2ix_2}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}}{\frac{1+x_1^2+x_2^2-x_1^2-x_2^2+1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}}=\frac{2x_1+2ix_2}{2}=x_1+ix_2$$

and this should be right. The problem comes for the second composition, indeed I get

$$\psi(\pi(x_1,x_2,x_3))=\psi (\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}+i\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})$$

$$=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3})^2+(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})^2}(2(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}),2(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}),(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3})^2+(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})^2-1)$$

The problem is that if I check for example the component one (where I should get $x_1$) I get

$$\frac{2(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3})}{1+(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3})^2+(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})^2}=\frac{2x_1}{(1-x_3)+(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3})^2+(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3})^2}$$

And I don't think this is going to be $x_1$ (maybe I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're computation so far is (almost) correct, you just need to go a little further with it. You have a small mistake in your last equality. It should be $$\frac{2\left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}\right)}{1 + \left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}\right)^2} = \frac{2x_1}{(1-x_3) + \frac{x_1^2}{1-x_3} + \frac{x_2^2}{1-x_3}}.$$ The key point you are missing, though, is that you also have the relation $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^3 = 1$, since $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ lies on the unit sphere. Therefore, you have the identity $$\frac{x_1^2}{1-x_3} + \frac{x_2^2}{1-x_3} = \frac{1 -x_3^2}{1 - x_3} = 1 + x_3.$$ In particular, you derive $$\frac{2\left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}\right)}{1 + \left(\frac{x_1}{1-x_3}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{x_2}{1-x_3}\right)^2} = \frac{2x_1}{(1-x_3) + (1+x_3)} = x_1.$$ Now you should try to work out the other components similarly! Hope this helped.

Comment: Wow! thank you so much! You really helped me gaining much time! ;-)